# Copy data from one table to another ERROR 1136

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to copy data from one table to another.

For that matter I'm using this:

```
INSERT INTO radacct_2011_2012 SELECT 'RadAcctId, AcctSessionId, AcctUniqueId, UserName, Realm, NASIPAddress, NASPortId, NASPortType, AcctStartTime, AcctStopTime, AcctSessionTime, AcctAuthentic, ConnectInfo_start, ConnectInfo_stop, AcctInputOctets, AcctOutputOctets, CalledStationId, CallingStationId, AcctTerminateCause, ServiceType, FramedProtocol, FramedIPAddress, AcctStartDelay, AcctStopDelay' from radacct where 'AcctStartTime' >= '2011' AND 'AcctStartTime' <= '2012';
```

When I try to run it I get the following error:

> ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

I'm reading about it and none of the solutions that I found helped me.

Comment: table definitions are required

Comment: you only set one value because you are escape the column list with `'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only `SELECT` one value because you escape the whole column list with `'`. So MySQL interpret this as a string value, not a column list.

So you should use the following query instead:

```
INSERT INTO `radacct_2011_2012` 
SELECT `RadAcctId`, `AcctSessionId`, `AcctUniqueId`, `UserName`, `Realm`, `NASIPAddress`, `NASPortId`, `NASPortType`, `AcctStartTime`, `AcctStopTime`, `AcctSessionTime`, `AcctAuthentic`, `ConnectInfo_start`, `ConnectInfo_stop`, `AcctInputOctets`, `AcctOutputOctets`, `CalledStationId`, `CallingStationId`, `AcctTerminateCause`, `ServiceType`, `FramedProtocol`, `FramedIPAddress`, `AcctStartDelay`, `AcctStopDelay` 
    FROM `radacct` 
    WHERE `AcctStartTime` >= '2011' AND `AcctStartTime` <= '2012';
```

There is a general problem on your query using the `'` in the wrong situations. You are using `'` on column names of the `WHERE` part too. MySQL compares `'AcctStartTime' >= '2011'` as false because the string values (in this example `AcctStartTime` and `2011`) are never equal. If you want to escape column names you have to use the backtick (``` `` ```).

You should read [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql) to get the difference between the different escape possibilities.

Tim provided [a demo](http://rextester.com/JAG30958) to confirm that double quotes (and single quotes too) can not be used to escape column names.

Comment: You can confirm for yourself that double quotes cannot be used to escape column names in MySQL [in this demo](http://rextester.com/JAG30958).

Answer (score 0):

Please check the no of columns in the first table and check the no of columns in the second table.

You should also match the order of the columns. i.e.

```
Table 1
col1 col2 col3 col4

Table 2
col1 col2 col3 col4

insert into table1 select col1,col2,col3,col4 from table2 where col1 = '2';
```

It will give error if the order is not match or the no of column is greater or less in the first table.

Comment: This should probably be a comment.

Comment: Already checked it like 5 times. The error was on the simple ' '